# T-SQL XML query filter node data

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xquery

I've got quite large Xml data stored into binary field. And want to extract minimal information as it has relationships to other tables.

An example of truncated xml data:

```
<CIVersion xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities" z:Id="i1">
  <CSettings xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" z:Id="i2">
    <d2p1:Name>V_TM</d2p1:Name>
  </CSettings>
  <ComponentModel xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" z:Id="i4">
    <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities">0</Id>
    <d2p1:Components>
      <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i5">
        <d2p1:Children>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i6">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.CIs" z:Id="i7" i:type="d7p1:SConConfiguration">
              <d2p1:RequiredNode z:Id="i9">
                <Name>TM</Name>
                <Version>v1.0.0</Version>
              </d2p1:RequiredNode>
              <d2p1:Name>EqConnection</d2p1:Name>
            </d2p1:Equipment>
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType i:nil="true" />
            <d2p1:Name>JobFactory</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters />
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i14">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment z:Ref="i7" />
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>Loadport</d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>
            <d2p1:Name>P2</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters>
              <d2p1:ComponentParameter z:Id="i15">
              </d2p1:ComponentParameter>
            </d2p1:Parameters>
            <d2p1:Type>Interfaces.IPort</d2p1:Type>
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i36">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.CIs" z:Id="i7" i:type="d7p1:SConConfiguration">
              <d2p1:RequiredNode z:Id="i8">
                <Name>TFF</Name>
                <Version>v1.0.2</Version>
              </d2p1:RequiredNode>
              <d2p1:Name>EqConnection2</d2p1:Name>
            </d2p1:Equipment>
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType i:nil="true" />
            <d2p1:Name>Synchronizer</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters />
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
        </d2p1:Children>
        <d2p1:Equipment z:Ref="i7" />
        <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>Equipment</d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>
        <d2p1:Name>V_TM</d2p1:Name>
      </d2p1:CellComponent>
    </d2p1:Components>
  </ComponentModel>
    <Name>Virt_TM</Name>
</CIVersion>
```

I need to extract only multiple values for 'd2p1:RequiredNode' node. So above example returns:

```
<RequiredNodes>
  <d2p1:RequiredNode z:Id="i9">
    <Name>TM</Name>
    <Version>v1.0.0</Version>
  </d2p1:RequiredNode>
  <:RequiredNode z:Id="i9">
    <Name>TFF</Name>
    <Version>v1.0.2</Version>
  </d2p1:RequiredNode>
</RequiredNodes>
```

This line returns the CSettings value:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities', 
        'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs' as "d2p1")

SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],
    Convert(Xml,[CONFIGURATION]).query('/CIVersion/CSettings') AS CSettings
  FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

I need same query correctly working for Oracle and MsSQL.

Comment: This is not valid XML. There's a few instances of `<:` ... it looks like you are missing the namespace in a couple places.

Comment: This is - at least for me - not clear... Is you question the last sentence (*I need same query correctly working for Oracle and MsSQL*)? XML support is highly vendor specific. Is your question how to retrieve the values? Try to provide a valid (and reduced!) XML. Just the amount needed to explain your issues...

Comment: Did not noticed that one part got copied wrong. It should <d2p1:RequiredNode instead <: ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities', 
        'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs' as "d2p1")

SELECT CAST('<RequiredNode>'+CAST(nd.query('.') as varchar(8000)) +'</RequiredNode>'AS xml)
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
CROSS APPLY [TABLE_NAME].[CONFIGURATION].nodes('//d2p1:RequiredNode') results(nd);
```

This query does not strip the name spaces from *name* and *version* but that should not be too hard. Here's the code that I used for testing this. Note that I added the missing namespaces to your XML.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#x') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #x;
CREATE TABLE #x (id int identity, xmldata xml);

INSERT #x (xmldata) VALUES 
('<CIVersion xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities" z:Id="i1">
  <CSettings xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" z:Id="i2">
    <d2p1:Name>V_TM</d2p1:Name>
  </CSettings>
  <ComponentModel xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" z:Id="i4">
    <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities">0</Id>
    <d2p1:Components>
      <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i5">
        <d2p1:Children>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i6">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.CIs" z:Id="i7" i:type="d7p1:SConConfiguration">
              <d2p1:RequiredNode z:Id="i9">
                <Name>TM</Name>
                <Version>v1.0.0</Version>
              </d2p1:RequiredNode>
              <d2p1:Name>EqConnection</d2p1:Name>
            </d2p1:Equipment>
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType i:nil="true" />
            <d2p1:Name>JobFactory</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters />
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i14">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment z:Ref="i7" />
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>Loadport</d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>
            <d2p1:Name>P2</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters>
              <d2p1:ComponentParameter z:Id="i15">
              </d2p1:ComponentParameter>
            </d2p1:Parameters>
            <d2p1:Type>Interfaces.IPort</d2p1:Type>
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
          <d2p1:CellComponent z:Id="i36">
            <d2p1:Children />
            <d2p1:Equipment xmlns:d7p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.CIs" z:Id="i7" i:type="d7p1:SConConfiguration">
              <d2p1:RequiredNode z:Id="i9">
                <Name>TFF</Name>
                <Version>v1.0.2</Version>
              </d2p1:RequiredNode>
              <d2p1:Name>EqConnection2</d2p1:Name>
            </d2p1:Equipment>
            <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType i:nil="true" />
            <d2p1:Name>Synchronizer</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Parameters />
          </d2p1:CellComponent>
        </d2p1:Children>
        <d2p1:Equipment z:Ref="i7" />
        <d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>Equipment</d2p1:EquipmentObjectType>
        <d2p1:Name>V_TM</d2p1:Name>
      </d2p1:CellComponent>
    </d2p1:Components>
  </ComponentModel>
    <Name>Virt_TM</Name>
</CIVersion>');

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities', 
        'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs' as "d2p1")

SELECT 
  RequiredNode = CAST('<RequiredNode>'+CAST(nd.query('.') as varchar(8000)) +'</RequiredNode>'AS xml),
  [Name]       = nd.value('(*:Name)[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  [Version]    = nd.value('(*:Version)[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
FROM #x
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('//d2p1:RequiredNode') results(nd);
```

**Results:**

```
<RequiredNode>
  <d2p1:RequiredNode xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" p1:Id="i9">
    <p2:Name xmlns:p2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities">TM</p2:Name>
    <p3:Version xmlns:p3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities">v1.0.0</p3:Version>
  </d2p1:RequiredNode>
</RequiredNode>
<RequiredNode>
  <d2p1:RequiredNode xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.ConfigData.FactoryEntities.CIs" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" p1:Id="i9">
    <p2:Name xmlns:p2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities">TFF</p2:Name>
    <p3:Version xmlns:p3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EM.FactoryEntities">v1.0.2</p3:Version>
  </d2p1:RequiredNode>
</RequiredNode>
```

Comment: Nice work! Is it possible to extract two values too from this query? So it shows name and version in own columns?

Comment: I updated my answer. Do note, because of time constraints and laziness, I apply a couple "not-best" (not terrible) practices such as `*:` for "any namespace" and `//` instead of the entire node path. Nonetheless, this should help. Cheers!